# Recyclerview animation for chat app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to replicate an animation used in **Quartz news app** for android.

Here is my code that I am using to accomplish this.

```
    //On clicking button start animation
private void handleActionButtonClick(Button actionButton) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Action button clicked");
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

            if (viewHolder instanceof OutgoingMessageViewHolder) {

                final OutgoingMessageViewHolder outgoingTextMessageViewHolder = (OutgoingMessageViewHolder) viewHolder;

                View messageView = outgoingTextMessageViewHolder.getTextView();

                int[] actionButtonPos = new int[2];
                actionButton.getLocationInWindow(actionButtonPos);

                int startX = actionButtonPos[0];
                int startY = actionButtonPos[1];

                int[] newMessagePos = new int[2];
                messageView.getLocationInWindow(newMessagePos);

                int x = newMessagePos[0] - startX;
                int y = newMessagePos[1] - startY;

                AnimatorSet flySet = new AnimatorSet();
                Animator flyX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(actionButton, View.TRANSLATION_X, (float) x);
                Animator flyY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(actionButton, View.TRANSLATION_Y, (float) y);

                flySet.playTogether(flyX, flyY);
                flySet.setDuration(450);
                flySet.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1.0f));

                flySet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        outgoingTextMessageViewHolder.getTextView().setText(actionButton.getText());
                        outgoingTextMessageViewHolder.itemView.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    }
                });

                AnimatorSet flyAndFadeSet = new AnimatorSet();
                ObjectAnimator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(actionButton, View.ALPHA, new float[]{0.0f}).setDuration(200);
                flyAndFadeSet.playSequentially(flySet, fade);

                final Button button = actionButton;

                flyAndFadeSet.addListener(new BaseAnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        button.setAlpha(0.0f);
                        hideUserActions();
                    }
                });

                flyAndFadeSet.start();
                hideOtherActions(actionButton, false);
            }
        }
    }, messageAnimator.getAddDuration());
}
```

But I am not able to get desired results as the position on end animation and view of message doesn't match with each other. Also I want to know is this the right way to do this.

Link to **Quartz app** implementation
Quartz app chat animation

[image]

Link to my implementation image

My chat app animation

[image: image2]

Comment: Can you make a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: Ok @kakabalik , I will create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the above.

Comment: @AMITKUMARKARN,did you find the solution for this.I want to make the same animation.can you please tell me how did you solve this.

Comment: @sai-durga I will post the code soon on github.

Comment: @AMITKUMARKARN,Thank you for your reply.Please share as early as possible..

Comment: @AMITKUMARKARN,can you please share the code with me.I have some urgency to do that UI part.

Comment: @SaiDurga Hi, Please use the following Github repository URL. I have shared a demo chat application there. [ChatUXDemo](https://github.com/amitkarn/ChatUXDemo)

Comment: @AMITKUMARKARN : Hey i have checked your demo in github but didn't get the left side typing animation working pattern. Tried with different MessageTypes as well. Can you please guide how to achieve this typing animation which used in quartz app same as screenshot.